# Redirection before invoking web method of asmx web service

Tags: c#, .net, soap, asmx

I have a asmx web service hosted at US as well as Canada. But there are few Canadian clients which points to US web service and I am not able to make any changes at client side to make them point to Canadian web service.

Is there any way I can redirect calls coming to US Web Service (Before web method hit) to Canadian web service? May be some HttpModule or SoapExtensions?

Comment: You can check the ip address and based on IP address you can redirect to US services.

Comment: I have a flag coming as web method parameter which would tell me whether request is for US or Canada. Problem is, How should I redirect? Response.Redirect doesn't work in ASMX.

Comment: You would have to make a request to other service not Response.Redirect();

Comment: I need to call in every web method? I am trying to avoid that actually. Any better way?

Comment: You can use HttpModule which will be excecuted for every request and in that you can do this.

Comment: Method name is defined in SOAP envelop, so I have to extract it from there to make a call to each method, sounds too dodgy...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing what I didn't want to.

I added proxy of own web service and called it by overwriting URL in each web method. I structured it by adding factory class.

Thanks!